# Putting VB.NET Controls in center of a sizable window

Tags: vb.net, resize, fullscreen

I'm creating a program in VB.NET (Microsoft's Visual Basic 2010).
I want to know if I can put all my content in the center of the screen. At the moment it's at the far top-left of the screen.
When the window size varies I want it to stay in the middle for all shapes and sizes. A similar example using HTML and CSS to achieve the above:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: The "Anchor" property helps to do that. Been too long since i used it to give you exact details but try out the various options for anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it using the `Form`'s `Resize` event but personally I'd use the `TableLayoutPanel` control ([documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel)).

Here are the steps:

1. Put all of your control into a single `Panel`
2. Add 3 columns and 3 rows to the `TableLayoutPanel`
3. Drag your new `Panel` into the center.
4. Dock the table so that it fills the whole `Form`.
5. Set all of the rows'/columns' size to 33.33%, this should now mean that your content will always be centered.

Answer (score 0):

I have another idea for this. First, create a `Panel` or something to hold all your content (if you haven't created one yet) and put all your `Control`s in it. Now select that `Panel` and  then go to the **Format >> Center in Form** menu and choose **Horizontal** first, then Vertical. Now you have two options to proceed with:

- If you want the whole thing to resize with the Form, which means like you want the distance around it to be constant, then set that `Panel`'s *Anchor* property to `Top, Bottom, Left, Right` (all).
- If you DON'T want the whole thing to resize with the Form, unlike the above, set that `Panel`'s *Anchor* property to `None`.

I hope it works. Sorry if I am not clear, that's all I can suggest.
I guess I am replying too late to this thread! ;-)
Cheers!
*– Sree*